# Mounting Overlayfs in a user namespace

Tags: linux, mount, overlayfs, userns

Is it possible to mount an Overlayfs filesystem as an unprivileged user in a user namespace in Linux kernels >4.3.3; it seems that the fix to [this vulnerability](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=2015-8660) has blocked this functionality entirely.

When I create a new user namespace with [clone()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), passing the `CLONE_NEWNS` flag and attempt to invoke mount with an overlayfs filesystem, I'm given permission denied. I can mount any other filesystem though.

Is there a way to work around this/am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It was not allowed to mount overlayfs within unprivileged user namespace up until and including kernel version v5.10. Not sure but if you can try a bind mount of the overlayfs into the user namespace.

Starting with kernel 5.11 however, the appropriate support has been added and you can now finally use them.