# Unable to run Julia "BinaryBuilder" as part of a CI process in Ubuntu 22.04 environment

Tags: ubuntu, docker, overlayfs

We have a GitLab CI runner set up on an on-prem computer. The runner is using the "shell" executor," so the jobs are running directly in the host environment.

We have an analysis tool in Julia. It has some dependencies on some C++ code. For the sake of build times, we would like to make a docker image that has these dependencies pre-built into julia packages. So we have a docker image based on Ubuntu 22.04 (and the CI host is 22.04, kernel 6.2). The image has julia installed into it. We are attempting to use [BinaryBuilder.jl](https://docs.binarybuilder.org/stable/) as the tool to build the julia packages.

When we run BinaryBuilder inside the dockerfile to build an image, we get an error `ABORTED (1: Operation not permitted)!`. Above, we see a warning stating

> Warning: Unable to run unprivileged containers on this system! This may be because your kernel does not support mounting overlay filesystems within user namespaces. To work around this, we will switch to using privileged containers. This requires the use of sudo. To choose this automatically, set the BINARYBUILDER_RUNNER environment variable to "privileged" before starting Julia.

This warning is called out in this [part of the FAQ](https://docs.binarybuilder.org/stable/FAQ/#At-line-XXX,-ABORTED-(Operation-not-permitted)!). However, the bug report in that FAQ is from kernel 4.2. I would *imagine* that this has gotten sorted out in more recent kernels, and the way I read [this posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288016/mounting-overlayfs-in-a-user-namespace) seems to indicate it was maybe fixed in 5.11. Also commit `92dbc9d` from the [5.11 changelog](https://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v5.x/ChangeLog-5.11) similarly seems to read that way to me.

So the core question is how to make the tool work in Ubuntu 22.04 in CI. One path is to grant it privileged access, which we could do, but obviously not ideal. I'm concerned that the `overlayfs` issue in their FAQ is a red herring that's been resolved in more recent kernels and there's some other issue going on.